# How to get hard disk serial number compatible with linux/windows

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Is there a way to get primary hard disk serial number independently from the OS?
In windows is quite easy with WMI or DllImport but I can't find any documentation about linux..
Alternatively is there a way to get a cross platform unique machine id? 
P.S. I don't care about virual machine cloning

Answer (score 2):

In linux terminal you can use the command below in order to get SERIAL of the HDD.

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL
```

where `/dev/sda` is generally primary HDD.

You can use static function like below to call Bash

```
public static string Bash(this string cmd)
{
    var escapedArgs = cmd.Replace("\"", "\\\"");

    var process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            Arguments = $"-c \"{escapedArgs}\"",
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
        }
    };
    process.Start();
    string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    process.WaitForExit();
    return result;
}
```

then execute

```
var output = "udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL".Bash();
```

Comment: This in a nice solution, in this way I have to check whether the OS is linux or windows

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

`udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sda | grep ID_SERIAL`

There are other methods but this one doesn't require root permissions.