# How to get hard drive serial number(s) in OS agnostic environment

Tags: c#, .net-core, cross-platform, mac-address, serial-number

I have a routine for gathering hard drive serial numbers and MAC addresses that functions robustly in Windows, however am looking for routines that work across all platforms that .net Core runs on.

I'm happy to write OS dependent routines but I can't see how it is possible on non-Windows machines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get hard disk serial number compatible with linux/windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325155/how-to-get-hard-disk-serial-number-compatible-with-linux-windows)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/883053/mac-os-x-equivalent-of-udevadm-info-a-n-dev-ttyacm0 for macos adaptation